# Is a spotify app always running once added by a user

Tags: api, spotify

Once an app has been added by a user is it always running in the background once the user has opened Spotify? So are the event listeners being fired even if the app hasn't been clicked on since opening Spotify?

Many thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is loaded when the user opens it. It doesn't matter if it is through the App Finder, by typing the apps' URI into the search box or reaching it through http://open.spotify.com/app/ (e.g. http://open.spotify.com/app/soundrop/).

It will stay loaded as long as it is open or has started playback. For example, if a user opens your app, starts playback using a List view component in the app, and switches app to Discover without starting to play music from there, your app will still be loaded and able to listen to events.

Your app will unload about 30 seconds after the user has navigated away from it without app playback, or 30 seconds after another app has taken over playback.