# Spotify - Run background process

Tags: spotify

I've already read the complete answer to this similar question ( [Is a spotify app always running once added by a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885065/is-a-spotify-app-always-running-once-added-by-a-user) ) but I wanted to better understand if there is *any* way to keep a background process running.

What I'd like to accomplish is to keep the listener of the songs played by a certain user running in order to collect data and then provide a sort of classification ( For example : how many rock songs have you listened to today? )

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer you linked is a complete description of how backgrounding works — apps are only kept alive in the background if they're actively controlling playback.